# Gulp: Recursively copy a file to every sub-directory

Tags: gulp

I have a file called `foo` and I want to copy it to every sub-directory.

For example if the current directory structure is:

```
- files
    - A/
    - B/
    - C/
    - D/
        - D1/
        - D2/
```

Then after the operation, it should be:

```
-files
    - foo
    - A/
        - foo
    - B/
        - foo
    - C/
        - foo
    - D/
        - foo
        - D1/
            - foo
        - D2/
            - foo
```

How can I do this using Gulp

Note that I do not know what the sub-directories will be before hand, so it needs to be done dynamically, and the paths cannot be hard-coded.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this using the `gulp-multi-dest` and `glob` packages:

```
const gulp = require('gulp'),
    multiDest = require('gulp-multi-dest'),
    glob = require('glob');

function copyToAll(done) {
    glob('files/**/', (err, matches) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error', err);
        } else {
            gulp.src('files/foo').pipe(multiDest(matches));
        }
        done();
    });
}

exports.default = copyToAll;
```